# "Tab Tree" or "Tabs Tree" (-s at the end)

Tags: names, nicknames

I created an extension for Firefox and named it "Tabs Tree". The extension is for managing browser tabs and representing them in the form of a tree structure. But now I think that I should have named it "Tab Tree" (without "-s"). Like "apple tree" or "orange tree".
But I used google and found usages of "Elements Tree" (https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/5.5.0-march-2013/UsersGuide/id/id_elements_tree.htm) and "Nodes Tree" (https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument113328) expressions. But also usage of "Element Tree" and "Node Tree".

Are both variants correct to use with that meaning? Or those people who used "Elements Tree" and "Nodes Tree" were wrong? And can I leave "Tabs Tree" as it is as it would be troublesome to change the name now?

Comment: You can call your product whatever you like (the concept of *grammatically correct* doesn't apply to proper nouns). But idiomatically in normal usage, [we don't normally pluralize compound "attributive nouns"](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/compound-nouns)

Comment: If it really is too much trouble to change, Tabs Tree would work.  (I know I'm interested in such an extension!)  But Tab Tree flows off the tongue a whole lot better.

Comment: Thanks for your opinions. Now I think I should change "Tabs Tree" to "Tab Tree" as apparently it seems more natural for the English language. (I am not a native English speaker and because of that I couldn't decide what "flows off the tongue" better)